# WIFI Drivers for ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 12.04, networking, wireless

I have just installed Ubuntu 14.04 and I am not getting  wifi signals.Can any one help me with this problem as I have no experience of using Ubuntu?

Comment: Did you check whether the WiFi is enabled ? i.e `Enable Wireless`System Settings -->Network.

Comment: please [edit] your question and provide the information referred to in this post which is Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have a broadcom wireless. You can test with the following command:

```
lspci -vnn | grep Network
```

If you have a broadcom card you should follow the steps here. -> [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Otherwise you should be able to find the drivers using additional drivers.

Take a look here -> [How do I install additional drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-additional-drivers)